# Head First design pattern program in C# -getting Duck.quackableDuck is inaccessible

Tags: c#

I am getting runtime error `Duck.quackableDuck` and `Duck.flyableDuck`  is inaccessible.

I have created two interfaces `FlyableDuck` and `QuackableDuck`. Class `MallardDuck` is inherited from class Duck.

```
using System;
//creating interfaces
public interface FlyableDuck
{
      void fly();
}

public interface QuackableDuck
{
     void quack();
}

//creating behavior classes
public class FlyWithWings:FlyableDuck
{
    public void fly()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am flying.");
    }
}

public class FlyNoWings: FlyableDuck
{
    public void fly()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I can't fly. :(");
    }
}

public class Quacking: QuackableDuck
{
    public void quack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Quack Quack!!");
    }
}

public class NoQuack : QuackableDuck
{
    public void quack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't quack :(");
    }
}
public class SqueakQuack : QuackableDuck
{
    public void quack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Squeak quack!!");
    }
}

//creating abstrack class
public abstract class Duck
{
    QuackableDuck quackableDuck;
    FlyableDuck flyableDuck;
    public Duck() { }
    public abstract void display();
    public void perfomFly()
    {
        flyableDuck.fly();     
    }
    public void perfomQuack()
    {
        quackableDuck.quack();
    }
    public void swim()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All ducks swim :)");
    }
}

//subclass
public class MallardDuck:Duck
{
    public MallardDuck()
     {
        quackableDuck = new Quacking();
        flyableDuck = new FlyWithWings();
     }
    public override void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Mallard Duck.");
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        MallardDuck mallard = new MallardDuck();
        mallard.perfomFly();
        mallard.perfomQuack();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Default accessor is `private` when not specified, not `protected`  as you are expecting.

Comment: Also, there's no need for a wall of code to describe this error, it could have been done in 6 lines of code. Next time: [mcve]

Comment: I think your understanding of inheritance needs some nurturing. Suggest you read some articles/tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These 2:

```
QuackableDuck quackableDuck;
FlyableDuck flyableDuck;
```

Are private (by default) so change it to:

```
public QuackableDuck quackableDuck;
public FlyableDuck flyableDuck;
```

You can also use protected/internal instead of public

Comment: I'd argue `protected` would be better suited.

Comment: @ChrisPickford The problem lies in its accessibility, I don't really care what  OP changes it to, but as every method was already public I decided this could/should be public too.

Comment: @ChrisPickford, why? those are composed field member and thus don't see any reason for them being `protected`

Comment: @EpicKip Except those are quite obviously private fields, not methods.

Comment: @Rahul Because he's already abstracted the private members' methods into public methods.

Comment: @ChrisPickford As I said I don't care what he changes it to, I just solved his accessibility problem. I made an edit saying you can use other access modifiers too